# Sorting the Jtree Alphabetically in JAVA using Hibernate technology

Tags: java, hibernate, sorting, jtree

I am debugging a Java App which is working with Hibernate.
It has a JTree in the main page which is filled dynamically form database and needed to be sorted out when it is shown.

I have tried to do the Sort in the query statement but it did not work.
I have also used some properties of the  JTree like `setSort()` function in order to sort the JTree elements but it is still not working properly.

Do you have any Idea how to sort this JTree elements when the data are shown!?

Comment: `I have tried to do the Sort in the query statement but it did not work`. Why not? What happened? If you're fetching from a DB it seems natural to sort it there rather than in the JTree.

Answer (score 1):

Create your own Node by extending `DefaultMutableTreeNode` and whenever a new child is added to the node sort it

```
class MyNode extends DefaultMutableTreeNode {

public MyNode(Object userObject) {
    super(userObject);
}

@Override
public void add(MutableTreeNode newChild) {
    super.add(newChild);
    sort();//add to tree and sort immediately use in case the model is small if large comment it and and call node.sort once you've added all the children
}

public void sort() {
    Collections.sort(children, compare());
}

private Comparator compare() {
    return new Comparator<DefaultMutableTreeNode>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(DefaultMutableTreeNode o1, DefaultMutableTreeNode o2) {
            return o1.getUserObject().toString().compareTo(o2.getUserObject().toString());
        }

    };

}
}
```

Example:Here I'm adding data's in descending order but will be displayed in ascending order as we sort every node as soon as we add a child to the parent

```
 JFrame frame = new JFrame();

    //Mock data
    MyNode root = new MyNode("Root");
    for (int i = 5; i > 0; i--) {
        MyNode parent = new MyNode("Parent" + i);
        for (int j = 5; j > 0; j--) {
            parent.add(new MyNode("Child" + j));
        }
        //parent.sort(); do like this if the data model is large and sort(); is commented in add Methods
        root.add(parent);
    }
    //root.sort();
    DefaultTreeModel tmodel = new DefaultTreeModel(root);
    JTree tree = new JTree(tmodel);

    frame.add(new JScrollPane(tree));

    frame.setTitle("Tree Editor Example");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);
```

Sample Output

[image]